# Swift: Selectively prevent auto screen rotation with SpriteKit scenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, device-orientation, screen-rotation

I have an iOS application that will have a number of SpriteKit scenes. These scenes should remain in the same orientation on the screen in both portrait and landscape. For example one scene will have a dual carriageway road running lengthways on the screen *ie.it will run up/down in portrait and left/right in landscape*. I don't want it to auto rotate with the device, although I will be rotating text on the screen to keep it readable (I can do this).

There are a number of other views (mainly text) that should still auto rotate so I don't want to deselect options in 'Deployment Info'.

Any ideas how to selectively allow/prevent auto rotation with the device? I want calculations for the vehicle positions to be unchanged between orientations. Ideally just rotate the scene.

Comment: the scene *will* rotate if you leave rotation enabled at top level. don't think u can electively turn rotation on or off for specific elements. however you can compensate and rotate the scene back if you want. you simply have your scene receive the rotation event, and make your compensation accordingly. you didn't mention if your scene is inside a SwiftUI app or a UIViewController. -- if you provide more information, i can post a proper solution. otherwise look up `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` for SwiftUI, and `viewWillTransition(...)` for UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I know it will rotate but that is the problem - I don't want it to, though I still want other views to rotate automatically.

Comment: The scenes are spritekit scenes and are brought into SwiftUI using the SpriteView command. I think I need to correct the rotation there before they are brought into SwiftUI to ensure the scaling is correct, so if I can react whenever the orientation changes and manually reverse the rotation, I would consider that an acceptable solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think your suggestion of using UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification and viewWillTransition should solve my problem, so I will look into implementing these.
Another possiblility is to disable rotation at the top level and do all my rotations manually for all views. This assumes that a scene can still be rotated manually when auto-rotation is disabled at the top level.
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a way to allow device rotation at top level, while simulating no rotation at SKScene level. you can receive device rotation events in SwiftUI and then pass that information down to your scene

```
struct GameSceneView: View {
    @State private var scene = TestScene()

    var body: some View {        
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Text("SwiftUI Text").font(.system(size:36))
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                let isLandscape = UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight
                let rotation = isLandscape ? CGFloat.pi/2 : 0
                scene.set(containerZRotation:rotation)
            }
    }
}
```

the corresponding SKScene simply needs to have a top level SKNode that contains all graphical elements as children. you set rotation accordingly on that container

```
class TestScene: SKScene {

    //property and function for handling rotation
    let container = SKNode()
    func set(containerZRotation:CGFloat) {
        container.zRotation = containerZRotation
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(container) //add container

        //add all child nodes to *container* rather than self
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "road")
        container.addChild(sprite)        
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided was quite helpful and more elegant than anything I would have come up with. I tried it with a single image to get it working. Had some issues initially with not seeing the image after rotation (except for upside down which acts like landscape) but this was resolved by setting the scene anchor point to (0.5, 0.5)